# Syntax error: Expected ";" but got keyword AS at [20:127] while creating a table in big query

Tags: sql, for-loop, google-bigquery, format, create-table

I have a project named `project_id` and a dataset named `dataset_id`. I am trying to create separate tables sharded by the date using a for loop in BigQuery using the UI.

The BigQuery for loop is not allowing me to create different tables using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command. Instead I am getting an error

> Syntax error: Expected ";" but got keyword AS at [20:127]

How can I correct this?

```
DECLARE end_of_month date;
DECLARE final_snapshot_date DEFAULT DATE '2020-10-01';
DECLARE initial_snapshot_date date DEFAULT DATE '2020-08-01';
DECLARE formatted_date STRING;

FOR date_suffix in (
  select * from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(initial_snapshot_date, final_snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) date
)
DO

  SET formatted_date = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", date_suffix.date);
  SET end_of_month = LAST_DAY(date_suffix.date);
  IF 
    date_suffix.date > final_snapshot_date THEN
    LEAVE; -- kill
  END IF;
  -- create some variables, through a temporary table called tablename.
  -- this is the table we want to shard with formatted_date and save
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    FORMAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_id.dataset_id.tablename_%s` (title STRING, publish_date INT64)", formatted_date) AS
  SELECT FORMAT(FORMAT_DATE("%b-%d-%Y", DATE "2008-12-25")) AS formatted;
  FROM `project_id.dataset_id.base_table_1`;

END FOR;
```

Line 20 where the error is, is the one that says

```
FORMAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_id.dataset_id.tablename_%s` (title STRING, publish_date INT64)", formatted_date) AS
  SELECT FORMAT(FORMAT_DATE("%b-%d-%Y", DATE "2008-12-25")) AS formatted;
```

Comment: @Daniel Zagales would you know how to fix this error?

Comment: @Jaytiger are you saying that you can wrap all of the variables with FORMAT?